# How should I run a mysql command with nomad and arguments?

Tags: nomad

I am interested in using nomad to initialize a mysql database on a windows server that is without docker.  I tried to create a job using the "exec" driver, "mysql" command, and an args argument with the host, username, password, etc.

```
job "gavin-setup" {

    datacenters = ["dc1"]

    group "gavin-setup-group" {

        task "setup" {
            driver = "exec"
            config = {
                command = "mysql"
                args = [
                    "-hlocalhost",
                    "-ugavin",
                    "-pgavin_secret",
                    "gavin_database",
                    "<",
                    "C:\\gavin\\config\\create.sql"
                ]
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The arguments aren't being passed along.  I also tried removing the args and just using the command which did not work:

`mysql -hlocalhost -ugavin -pgavin_secret gavin_database < C:\\gavin\\config\\create.sql`

Is it possible to do this kind of database initialization setup on a first-time run of the application?  Should nomad be capable of doing this?  If not - should I be using some other process to do this kind of setup?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the full path to the mysql.exe and discovered that `nomad logs -stderr <assoc-id>` was really helpful.

```
job "gavin-setup" {

    datacenters = ["dc1"]

    group "gavin-setup-group" {

        task "create_db" {
            driver = "exec"
            config = {
                command = "C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/bin/mysql.exe"
                args = [
                    "-uroot",
                    "-pgavin_secret",
                    "-e",
                    "create database if not exists gavin_db;"
                ]
            }
        }

    }

}
```